# Парсинг Json файла с помощью Gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson, pojo

В папке ...\app\src\main\res\raw есть файл test.json:

```
{
  "qotd_date":"2021-07-22T00:00:00+00:00",
  "quote":
  {
    "id":63363,
    "dialogue":false,
    "private":false,
    "tags":[],
    "url":"https://favqs.com/quotes/meister-eckhart/63363-be-willing-to-",
    "favorites_count":1,
    "upvotes_count":0,
    "downvotes_count":0,
    "author":"Meister Eckhart",
    "author_permalink":"meister-eckhart",
    "body":"Be willing to be a begineer every single morning."
  }
}
```

Для него я создаю классы:

```
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("qotd_date")
    @Expose
    public String qotdDate;
    @SerializedName("quote")
    @Expose
    public Quote quote;

}
```

И

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
public class Quote {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    public Integer id;
    @SerializedName("dialogue")
    @Expose
    public Boolean dialogue;
    @SerializedName("private")
    @Expose
    public Boolean _private;
    @SerializedName("tags")
    @Expose
    public List<Object> tags = null;
    @SerializedName("url")
    @Expose
    public String url;
    @SerializedName("favorites_count")
    @Expose
    public Integer favoritesCount;
    @SerializedName("upvotes_count")
    @Expose
    public Integer upvotesCount;
    @SerializedName("downvotes_count")
    @Expose
    public Integer downvotesCount;
    @SerializedName("author")
    @Expose
    public String author;
    @SerializedName("author_permalink")
    @Expose
    public String authorPermalink;
    @SerializedName("body")
    @Expose
    public String body;
}
```

Далее начинаю работать с Gson:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.FileReader;

public class GsonParser {

    public Example parser() {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("test.json")) {

            Example example = gson.fromJson(reader, Example.class);

            return example;
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

После чего пробую вывести результат в Log:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GsonParser gsonParser = new GsonParser();
        Example example = gsonParser.parser();

        Log.d("log1",example.toString());

    }
}
```

Но получаю `NullPointerException`
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить

Comment: Скорее всего не находит `test.json`, поставьте логгер там где у вас кидается `Exception` в классе `GsonParser`  - зря его заглушили

Comment: Поток на файл в `raw` нужно открывать так: `context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename)`

Comment: @woesss, расскажите пожалуйста, поподробнее, как это сделать, до меня пока не доходит, как применить это в моём коде

Comment: @НиколайСеменов, вы сами себе усложняете поиск ошибок, оставляя пустым `catch` блок. Обработайте ошибку, хотя бы распечатайте ее в лог: `catch (IOException exception) { Log.e("GsonParser", "Cannot parse json", exception) }`. Потом посмотрите внимательно стектрейс ошибки. И дальше уже поймете конкретно, что у вас не так с кодом.

Comment: __Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы считать содержимое файла из `raw` директории воспользуйтесь методом [openRawResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#openRawResource(int)), этот метод на вход принимает идентификатор raw-ресурса:

```java
context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test)
```

Ваш код тогда будет выглядеть так:

```java
try (InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(resources.openRawResource(R.raw.test))) {
    return gson.fromJson(reader, Example.class);
} catch (IOException exception) {
    Log.e("GsonParser", "Cannot parse json", exception);
    return null;
}
```

**Никогда** не оставляйте блок `catch` пустым, это затрудняет поиск ошибок!

Comment: Премного благодарен!